# Cannot read property 'setParams' of null on trying to implement Lightning Expense tracker application

Tags: lightning, aura

I have followed the steps as outlined in the lightning components developer guide. I am facing issue while implementing events (to update expense records when reimbursed checkbox is clicked). 
On clicking/unclicking the checkbox, the color of the expense panel does change but it also throws the error :

> Action failed: starhunter:expenseList$controller$update [Cannot read
>   property 'setParams' of null] Failing descriptor:
>   {starhunter:expenseList$controller$update}

The expenseListController code:

```
({ 
  update: function(component, evt, helper) { 
    var expense = component.get("v.expense"); // Note that updateExpense matches the name attribute in <aura:registerEvent> 
    var updateEvent = component.getEvent("updateExpense"); 
    updateEvent.setParams({ "expense": expense }).fire(); 
  } 
})
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code as well?

Comment: The expenseListController :                                                                            
 ({
update: function(component, evt, helper) {
var expense = component.get("v.expense");
// Note that updateExpense matches the name attribute in <aura:registerEvent>
var updateEvent = component.getEvent("updateExpense");
updateEvent.setParams({ "expense": expense }).fire();
}
})

Comment: You have not registered the event `updateExpense` or you have not defined it. Make sure it's a component event.

Comment: Yeah it is a component event. Also the registerEvent tag was included : <aura:registerEvent name="upateExpense" type="c:updateExpenseItem"/> .